# How to extract a curve using pycatia

Tags: python, catia

I need to extract a curve in pycatia. The curve is an intersect between a plane and a geometry (it's a closed loop, single part, no self-intersections).

In the end, all I need is the curve per se. The way I obtain it doesn't matter, as long as I obtain a CSV with its points.

What I've been using is finding the curve, creating the extremums (and picking the smallest X), splitting the curve with it, and creating N points at every 1/N of the length of the curves. This gives me 2N points, but it returns a ton of errors. Is there an easier way of doing this?

My code:

```
from pycatia import catia

def getPosition(Part,SPwb,Item):
    reference = Part.create_reference_from_object(Item) #Get point position
    measurable = SPwb.get_measurable(reference)
    return measurable.get_point()


step = 5e-4
sp = np.arange(0, 1+step, step)
scale = 1e3

caa = catia()
document = caa.active_document
part = document.part
spa_workbench = document.spa_workbench()

HBs = part.hybrid_bodies
hsf = part.hybrid_shape_factory
dirX = hsf.add_new_direction_by_coord(1,0,0) #Direction X

coords = []

for geomSet in HBs:
    HB = HBs.get_item_by_name(geomSet.name)
    HS = HB.hybrid_shapes
    for geom in HS:
        if geom.name == 'NAME':
            extremum = hsf.add_new_extremum(geom,dirX,0)
            HB.append_hybrid_shape(extremum)
            part.update() 
            xLE, yLE, zLE = getPosition(part,spa_workbench,extremum)
            hsf.delete_object_for_datum(extremum)
            part.update()
            for pct in sp:
                point = hsf.add_new_point_on_curve_from_percent(geom, pct, True)
                HB.append_hybrid_shape(point)
                part.update()
                x, y, z = getPosition(part, spa_workbench, point)
                hsf.delete_object_for_datum(point)
                part.update()
                coords.append(((x - xLE)/scale, (z - zLE)/scale, (y - yLE)/scale))
```

Comment: What errors do you get? In which line?

Comment: all the getPosition() calls error out:

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, 'ExecuteScript(Evaluate, MemoryMacro, get_point)\nExecution error\n(The scripting engine for CATScript has reported the following error:\n\nSource: CATIAMeasurable\nDescription: The method GetPoint failed\nLine: 4\nColumn: 12\n)\n', None, 0, -2147467259), None)

Comment: Does this error occur on all points or only some? Or also on the extremum?

Comment: All points, extremums as well

Comment: Check that your extremum is a point result instead of perhaps a line - which you may see if your intersected object has flat sides.

Comment: I think I solved it. It needs to be an open curve, not a closed loop. I copied/pasted the intersect and split with two other points, and now it works